# Do not serialize empty strings to XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I've got a library project where object are serialized to XML format for further download by users in ASP.NET application. Additionaly i've used XSD to generate types for serialization. The number of types for serialization is very big. Each type is serialized to its own XML. Some types have string properties, sometimes those properties contains empty strings. During serializations those properties are been serialized to some like this

```
<propertyName />
```

So this properties become invalid by XSD (they are not required but have some restrictions like string minimal string length etc.

Is there any way to configure XMLSerializer not no serialize empty strings to empty xml elements for all types that are been serialized.

For serializing I use `System.Xml.XmlSerializer`.

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to implement xml writer/reader for the serializations to work;

You would also need to edit the writer and reader to work on conditionals, first check if a param is an empty string before writing a new xml element and placing its value.

```
if(string.isNullOrEmpty(this.testString)){
 break; // if in a loop of params, just giving an example, rest of the                     
        // xmlwriter implementation would be normal
        // note you might need to also implement the reader a bit different - unsure of that.
}
```

Reference material:

http://forum.codecall.net/topic/58239-c-tutorial-reading-and-writing-xml-files/
http://www.dotnetperls.com/xmlwriter

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to go back and read the XML specification carefully. See http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-starttags
where it says:

> [Definition: An element with no content is said to be empty.] The representation >of an empty element is either a start-tag immediately followed by an end-tag, or 
>   an empty-element tag. [Definition: An empty-element tag takes a special form:]

So this:

```
<propertyName />
```

is exactly equivalent to this:

```
<propertyName></propertyName>
```

...and any XML processor that treats them differently is not conforming to the specification.

I find that people often confuse the following concepts when dealing with XML and XML schema:

- tag with empty content.

Either form is acceptable. Empty is not the same as 'null' or 'nil'.
An element is allowed to be empty or nil even if minOccurs=1 in the schema.

- null value / nil value.

Not the same as empty content. XML has a specific attribute to indicate that the value is 'nil'.

- missing tag.

The tag is entirely omitted from the XML document. Not the same as empty or nil.
This *will* trigger a validation error if minOccurs=1

Comment: Unfortunately but those XSD are been provided by 3rd party developers and I've got no influence on the. So I have to consume them "as it is".

Comment: But you said, in your first post Some types have string properties, sometimes those properties contains empty strings. During serializations those properties are been serialized to some like this

<propertyName />

So this properties become invalid by XSD (they are not required but have some restrictions like string minimal string length etc.

Is there any way to configure XMLSerializer not no serialize empty strings to empty xml elements for all types that are been serialized.

Comment: ...so I am somewhat puzzled about your real requirement. Can you try explaining the problem more clearly?

Answer (score 0):

If you are fetching data from database then you can apply if condition like :-

```
if (Dbobject.propertyName == ""){
    XMLObject.propertyName = null;
} else {
    XMLObject.propertyName = Dbobject.propertyName;
}
```

The null values will not be serialized and the property name will be skipped during XML Serialization.